# Why my Python code is extracting the same data for all the elements in my list?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My project consists of making a competitive watch table for hotel rates for an agency. It is a painful action that I wanted to automate, the code extract correctly the name of hotels and the prices I want to extract but it's working correctly only for the first hotel and I don't know where is the problem. I provide you with the code and the output, if any of you can help me and thank you in advance.
[image]

**NB : the code 2 works correctly but when i've added more operations the problem appeared**

**code 1**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import time
from time import sleep
import ast
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\marketing2\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/')

# params to select
params = {
    'destination': 'Tozeur',
    'date_from': '11/09/2021',
    'date_to': '12/09/2021',
    'bedroom': '1'
}

# select destination
destination_select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ville_des'))))
destination_select.select_by_value(params['destination'])

# select bedroom
bedroom_select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'select_ch'))))
bedroom_select.select_by_value(params['bedroom'])

# select dates
script = f"document.getElementById('checkin').value ='{params['date_from']}';"
script += f"document.getElementById('checkout').value ='{params['date_to']}';"
script +=  f"document.getElementById('depart').value ='{params['date_from']}';"
script += f"document.getElementById('arrivee').value ='{params['date_to']}';"
driver.execute_script(script)

# submit form
btn_rechercher = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="boutonr"]')))
btn_rechercher.click()

urls = []
hotels = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'produit_affair')]")))

for hotel in hotels:
    link = hotel.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='tittre_hotel']/a").get_attribute("href")
    urls.append(link)

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
       
    def existsElement(xpath):
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id(xpath);
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return "false"
        else:
            return "true"
   
    if (existsElement('result_par_arrangement')=="false"):
   
        btn_t = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="moteur_rech"]/form/div/div[3]/div')))

        btn_t.click()
        sleep(10)
    else :
        pass
               
    
    try:
        name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bloc_titre_hotels']/h2"))).text
        arropt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'line_result')][1]")
        opt = arropt.find_element_by_tag_name("b").text
        num = len(arropt.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"))
        optiondata = {}
        achats = {}
        marges= {}
        selection = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("arrangement"))

        for i in range(num):
            try:
                selection = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("arrangement"))
                selection.select_by_index(i)
                time.sleep(2)

                arr = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='arrangement']/option[@selected='selected']").text
                prize = driver.find_element_by_id("prix_total").text

                optiondata[arr] = (int(prize))

                btn_passe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="resultat"]/div/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div')))
                btn_passe.click()



                # params to select
                params = {
                            'civilite_acheteur': 'Mlle',
                            'prenom_acheteur': 'test',
                            'nom_acheteur': 'test',
                            'e_mail_acheteur': 'test@gmail.com',
                            'portable_acheteur': '22222222',
                            'ville_acheteur': 'Test',
                        }

                # select civilite
                civilite_acheteur = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'civilite_acheteur'))))
                civilite_acheteur.select_by_value(params['civilite_acheteur'])

                # saisir prenom 
                script  = f"document.getElementsByName('prenom_acheteur')[0].value ='{params['prenom_acheteur']}';"
                script += f"document.getElementsByName('nom_acheteur')[0].value ='{params['nom_acheteur']}';"
                script += f"document.getElementsByName('e_mail_acheteur')[0].value ='{params['e_mail_acheteur']}';"
                script += f"document.getElementsByName('portable_acheteur')[0].value ='{params['portable_acheteur']}';"
                script += f"document.getElementsByName('ville_acheteur')[0].value ='{params['ville_acheteur']}';"
                driver.execute_script(script)

                # submit form
                btn_agence = driver.find_element_by_id('titre_Nabeul')
                btn_agence.click()

                btn_continuez = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'boutonr')))
                btn_continuez.click()

                achat = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]').text.replace(' TND', ''))

                achats[arr]=achat

                marge =int(((float(prize) - float(achat)) / float(achat)) * 100);
                marges[arr]=marge
                optiondata[arr]=prize,achat,marge
                
                
                driver.get(url)
                btn_display = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="moteur_rech"]/form/div/div[3]/div')))

                btn_display.click()
                sleep(10)
               

            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                pass

            

    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    
  s="- {} | {} : {}".format(name, opt, optiondata)
    print(s)  
   

    ds = []

    for l in s.splitlines():
        d = l.split('-')
        if len(d) > 1:
            df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(d[1].strip()))
            ds.append(df)

    for df in ds:
        df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    df = pd.concat(ds, axis= 1)

    cols = df.columns

    cols = [((col.split('.')[0], col)) for col in df.columns]

    df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)

    print(df.T)    

#print("{} : {} - {}".format(name, opt, optiondata))
```

**code 2**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException,NoSuchElementException
urls = []
hotels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'produit_affair')]")
for hotel in hotels:
    link = hotel.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='tittre_hotel']/a").get_attribute("href")
    urls.append(link)
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='bloc_titre_hotels']/h2").text
        arropt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'line_result')][1]")
        opt = arropt.find_element_by_tag_name("b").text
        num = len(arropt.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"))
        optiondata = {}
        selection = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("arrangement"))
        for i in range(num):
            try:
                selection = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("arrangement"))
                selection.select_by_index(i)
                time.sleep(2)
                arr = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='arrangement']/option[@selected='selected']").text
                prize = driver.find_element_by_id("prix_total").text
                optiondata[arr]=prize
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                pass
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    print("{} : {} - {} - {}".format(name,opt,num,optiondata))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that it can't access to the element listing arrangements for the rest of the hotels in the list i've added a function that tests the presence of the data and it workod

```
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
       
    def existsElement(xpath):
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id(xpath);
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return "false"
        else:
            return "true"
   
    if (existsElement('result_par_arrangement')=="false"):
   
        btn_t = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="moteur_rech"]/form/div/div[3]/div')))

        btn_t.click()
    else :
        pass
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Your code is outdated. The HTML has been changed/updated and elements such as the one with identity `boutonr` doesn't exist on the page anymore.
2. Your loop and order of execution is wrong so this makes the code evaluating still the same fields.
3. You should not use or at least minimise the usage of `time.sleep()` to an absolute minimum as it is a waste of time for your code execution. Use `WebDriverWait(...)` instead

I don't speak French so I could not understand what you are after in your code, but this minimised example below should help you to understand the principle.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/')

# params to select
params = {  'destination': 'Nabeul',
            'date_from': '25/08/2021',
            'date_to': '26/08/2021',
            'bedroom': '1' }

# select destination
destination_select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ville_des'))))
destination_select.select_by_value(params['destination'])

# select bedroom
bedroom_select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'select_ch'))))
bedroom_select.select_by_value(params['bedroom'])

# select dates
script = f"document.getElementById('checkin').value ='{params['date_from']}';"
script += f"document.getElementById('checkout').value ='{params['date_to']}';"
script +=  f"document.getElementById('depart').value ='{params['date_from']}';"
script += f"document.getElementById('arrivee').value ='{params['date_to']}';"
driver.execute_script(script)

# submit form
btn_rechercher = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@onclick="return submit_hotel_recherche()"]')))
btn_rechercher.click()

urls = []
hotels = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'produit_affair')]")))

for hotel in hotels:
    link = hotel.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='tittre_hotel']/a").get_attribute("href")
    urls.append(link)

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bloc_titre_hotels']/h2"))).text
        arropt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'line_result')][1]")
        opt = arropt.find_element_by_tag_name("b").text
        num = len(arropt.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"))
        optiondata = {}
        achats = {}
        marges= {}

        for i in range(num):
            try:
                selection = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'arrangement')))).select_by_index(i)
                time.sleep(0.5)

                arr = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='arrangement']/option[@selected='selected']"))).text
                prize = driver.find_element_by_id("prix_total").text

                optiondata[arr] = int(prize)

            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                pass

        print("{} : {} - {}".format(name, opt, optiondata))

    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
Byzance Nabeul : Chambre Double - {'All Inclusive soft': 93, 'Demi Pension': 38, 'Petit Dejeuner': 28, 'Pension Complete': 78}
Palmyra Club Nabeul Nabeul : Double Standard - {'All Inclusive soft': 92}
```

The following code goes to the payment page and extracts all the info there:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/')

# params to select
params = {
    'destination': 'Nabeul',
    'date_from': '29/08/2021',
    'date_to': '30/08/2021',
    'bedroom': '1'
}

# select destination
destination_select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ville_des'))))
destination_select.select_by_value(params['destination'])

# select bedroom
bedroom_select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'select_ch'))))
bedroom_select.select_by_value(params['bedroom'])

# select dates
script = f"document.getElementById('checkin').value ='{params['date_from']}';"
script += f"document.getElementById('checkout').value ='{params['date_to']}';"
script +=  f"document.getElementById('depart').value ='{params['date_from']}';"
script += f"document.getElementById('arrivee').value ='{params['date_to']}';"
driver.execute_script(script)

# submit form
btn_rechercher = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@onclick="return submit_hotel_recherche()"]')))
btn_rechercher.click()

urls = []
hotels = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'produit_affair')]")))

for hotel in hotels:
    link = hotel.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='tittre_hotel']/a").get_attribute("href")
    urls.append(link)

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bloc_titre_hotels']/h2"))).text
        arropt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'line_result')][1]")
        opt = arropt.find_element_by_tag_name("b").text
        num = len(arropt.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"))
        optiondata = {}
        achats = {}
        marges= {}
        try:
            selection = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'arrangement'))))
            time.sleep(0.5)

            arr = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='arrangement']/option[@selected='selected']"))).text
            prize = driver.find_element_by_id("prix_total").text

            optiondata[arr] = (int(prize))

            btn_passe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'resa')))
            btn_passe.click()

            tot = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'montant_total_apres_code')))
            total = int(tot.text.replace(' €', ''))

            # params to select
            params = {
                        'civilite_acheteur': 'Mlle',
                        'prenom_acheteur': 'test',
                        'nom_acheteur': 'test',
                        'e_mail_acheteur': 'test@gmail.com',
                        'portable_acheteur': '22222222',
                        'ville_acheteur': 'Test',
                    }

            # select civilite
            civilite_acheteur = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'civilite_acheteur'))))
            civilite_acheteur.select_by_value(params['civilite_acheteur'])

            # saisir prenom 
            script  = f"document.getElementsByName('prenom_acheteur')[0].value ='{params['prenom_acheteur']}';"
            script += f"document.getElementsByName('nom_acheteur')[0].value ='{params['nom_acheteur']}';"
            script += f"document.getElementsByName('e_mail_acheteur')[0].value ='{params['e_mail_acheteur']}';"
            script += f"document.getElementsByName('portable_acheteur')[0].value ='{params['portable_acheteur']}';"
            script += f"document.getElementsByName('ville_acheteur')[0].value ='{params['ville_acheteur']}';"
            driver.execute_script(script)

            # submit form
            btn_agence = driver.find_element_by_class_name('continuez_resa')
            btn_agence.click()
            
            achat1 = int(driver.find_element_by_id('montant_a_payer').text.replace(' €', ''))
            achat = int(driver.find_element_by_id('montant_restant').text.replace(' €', ''))
            achat3 = float(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="ligne_interne_total"]/div[3]/div[@class="prix_total1 text_shadow"]').text.replace(' TND', ''))
            achats[arr]=achat

            marge =int(((float(prize) - float(achat)) / float(achat)) * 100);
            marges[arr]=marge
            optiondata[arr]=prize,total,achat1,achat,achat3,marge

        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass

        print("{} : {} - {}".format(name, opt, optiondata))

    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Byzance Nabeul : Chambre Double - {'Petit Dejeuner': (36, 41, 12, 29, 4.0, 24)}
```

Where:

```
36 = Prix Total
41 = Montant Total
12 = Montant de l'acompte
29 = Vous payerez le reste à votre arrivée à l'hôtel
4.0 = Total taxe de séjour à payer sur place à l'hôtel est
24 = Marges
```

Hotel page:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response, here is the question with more details i hope you cans understand what i need to do with the 2nd codre [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741521/how-to-extract-data-from-an-element-list-python) the most important data i need to extract are "achat" and "marge"

Comment: What is "achat"? On the last payment page there are 3 prices: 1) Montant de l'acompte, 2) Montant à payer à votre arrivée à l'hôtel, 3) Total taxe de séjour à payer sur place à l'hôtel est. Which one is "achat" ?

Comment: it's the "Montant à payer à votre arrivée à l'hôtel"

Comment: still have the problem :( it's not working but thank you anyways

Comment: The code above produced the above output that you requested so what is not working?

Comment: the probleme that it still extracting the same data for all the liste of the hotels i've changed the code with the elements i want to show and the probleme reappeared the final output is every hotel with it's prices and in your code ou choosed the bouton "je paye en ligne" but i want to click on "Je passe à l'agence" bouton when i've changed the code still the same problem in the image above the code all hotels with same data i ve changed the code and i hope you  understand me

Comment: I just checked and the script still produces the same output as above. So I don't understand what you mean ? The script walks through 5 pages: 1st page => open start page and make selections then click "RECHERCHER" button, 2nd page => get list of hotels, 3rd page => go to first hotel from the list and extract prices then click "continuez" button, 4th page => fill in personal data and extract total price then click "Continues votre reservation", 5th page => extract prices and calculate marge. There is no "Je passe à l'agence" button that you are talking about.

Comment: Maybe you have different page than me because you are an agent?

Comment: i've added images please check them thank you.

Comment: As I already said I don't see those two buttons on the hotel page. I only see one "continuez" button (see image added above). If you are resale agent with an account you will most probably get a different page with different options. I'm sorry but in this case I don't think I can help you with that.

Comment: problem solved thank you very much for your help !!

Answer (score 2):

You are using sleeps to load the pages in your first example but not in your second one (the one that you state works just fine).

This is typically not the way you want to actually use selenium and leads me to believe that your timing is off.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35262031/496405) shows you how to use "Explicit Waits" on "expected_conditions" to not have "specific timings" which can/will fail.

You even create a `wait` object but never use it.

Use it in conjunction with `expected_conditions` and remove the specific timed sleeps and things will get better.

[expected_conditions docs are here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html)